# Angular Material, why animations don`t work?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using angular material 8.1.3 and I have no idea why animations don't work.
Animations don't work in whole app but I`m presenting menu component.

It should be animation like in this example:][1]

The same problem is with toggles etc.

I have material module like this:

```
import {A11yModule} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import {PortalModule} from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import {CdkStepperModule} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {CdkTreeModule} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatBadgeModule} from '@angular/material/badge';
import {MatBottomSheetModule} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    A11yModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {
}
```

And menu.module.ts

```
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {MenuComponent} from './menu.component';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {FontAwesomeModule} from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MaterialModule} from '../material.module';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    RouterModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    MenuComponent
  ]
})
export class MenuModule {
}
```

menu.component.html

```
<div class="menu-container">
  <nav mat-tab-nav-bar [backgroundColor]="background">
    <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let tab of tabs" 
       [routerLink]="tab.link"
       (click)="activeLink = tab.name"
       [active]="activeLink == tab.name"> {{tab.name}}</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't import `BrowserModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule` twice in your application , so import them only in your `app.module.ts` or your shared module.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I corrected as you said but animations still dont`t work, Is there any additional thing wchich need to be done?

Comment: Please don't accept the answer, when the problem is not solved.